# EdX API: How to get threads and commnets of a course?

Tags: api, http, openedx, edx, embedxcode

I am using Edx api described here: https://courses.edx.org/api-docs/

I am geeting courses list from https://courses.edx.org/api/courses/v1/courses/

And i am trying to get threads of a course:
https://courses.edx.org/api/discussion/v1/threads/?course_id=<COURSE_ID>

For example:
https://courses.edx.org/api/discussion/v1/threads/?course_id=AdelaideX%2FHumBio101x%2F1T2015

Response:

```
{
  "developer_message": "Course not found."
}
```

But that course id was get from courses list api.

Any ideas how to get threads and comments of a course?

Comment: Could you add the full request you're using? Maybe with cURL?

Answer (score 0):

You get `Course not found` because you do not have the authority to access the course you asked for. again try to get threads for a course you have enrolled in. (must be HTML encoded)
like: `course-v1:edX%2BDemoX.1%2B2T2019` [an example](https://courses.edx.org/api/discussion/v1/threads/?course_id=course-v1:edX%2BDemoX.1%2B2T2019)
this time you will get the discussion threads.
Why course API response contains items that you don't have access to? actually I'm not sure. but maybe it's better to ask in their [discussion forum](https://discuss.openedx.org/).